# Reading many files causes memory issues?

Tags: c#, file, memory, memory-management, foreach

I am searching through many files on the system to find text in them for a computer searching program that I am writing. However, when larger files get read, the lines stay in memory making it get to over a GB of ram usage. I was wondering what the problem was. Here's my code.

```
    private int SearchInFile(SearchResult searchResult, Options options) {
        if (searchQuery.inFile.Length == 0) return -1;
        if (!options.searchOnlyInTextFiles || searchResult.type.Equals(".txt")) {
            try {
                int index = 0;
                foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(searchResult.path)) {
                    index++;
                    if (line.Contains(searchQuery.inFile)) return index;
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In managed memory, growing memory usage is normal. The GC will clean up once there is memory pressure.

Comment: @Sefe but gigabytes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was wondering why so much memory was being used in the for loop

Comment: Well, you read a lot of files, and if there's no reason for the GC to collect the memory, it's more efficient if it does not. Does your program behave badly?

Comment: Leave memory management to the GC. Don't interfere as this hurts efficiency. The GC knows how much memory is used and will collect if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open up a stream, like a FileStream, and only read, say, 1024 bytes at a time. You should inspect the bytes, and build up only the current line in RAM, until you find a new line character, and then look in that line for the text you are looking for. This way, you only hold the line you are currently inspecting in RAM.

You need to be careful how the line endings are defined though. Different text files have different ways of defining where lines end. In addition to that, you need to be aware of how the .txt files are encoded, UTF8, ASCII etc.

If you are careful, you can ensure that your application never uses more than a certain amount of RAM, and the garbage collector be less busy.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem exactly how I needed.